# How to log content of emails so repeat emails aren't sent again?

Tags: python, email, logging

I use this code to scrape odds data. It sends me an email every time there is a discrepancy in odds between bookmakers. I run the code multiple times everyday manually through the terminal. As I run the code multiple times a day, I get many duplicate emails of the same instances of odds discrepancies. The content of the emails is exactly the same, except for the subject line which displays the time when the emails were sent. Is there anyway to log the content of emails so the the code prevents emails being sent which are the same? I would like to prevent the emails being sent not just filter them out once they've been sent through Gmail. The code would also have to refresh each day so the log of the content is emptied. Sorry for the complex question.

Comment: you could rather use DataFrame instead of log to keep this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could log the data to a CSV file in append mode every time an email is sent. This can be done using Python's [CSV module][1]. If the CSV file exists read it and make sure the values haven't been already written to that file. Name the file with the current date. This way you can keep or delete the logs as required. I'm assuming the variables you want to check are `dfm2` and `dfm3`, but you can replace with any other variables you need to check. It's a good idea to read from this link to make sure it's set how you want it to work. There are other logging options, but using a csv file is an easy solution.

```
from datetime import datetime
from os import path
import csv

# your code prior to below line here
dfmerge5 = dfmerge1.loc[dfmerge1['ComparedOdds'] == 1, 'AvgOdds'].values
csv_file = f'<path to log file>/odds-log-{datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m")}.csv')

for dfm2, dfm3, dfm4, dfm5 in zip(dfmerge2, dfmerge3, dfmerge4, dfmerge5):
    mail_sent = False
    if path.isfile(csv_file):
        with open(csv_file, 'r') as r_file:
            c_reader = csv.reader(r_file)
            for row in c_reader:
               if dfm2 in row and dfm3 in row:
                   mail_sent = True
    if not mail_sent:
        with open(csv_file, 'a') as w_file:
        c_writer = csv.writer(w_file)
        c_writer.writerow([dfm2, dfm3])
        dt = datetime.now()
        subject = f'Overlay - {dt}'
        body = f'Hi Harrison,\n\nYou have one overlay:\n\nFor {dfm2} in {dfm3}, Bet365 are displaying odds of ${dfm4}, where as the average odds are          ${dfm5}.\n\nBest of luck.'
        message = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'
        mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        mail.ehlo()
        mail.starttls()
        mail.login
        mail.sendmail(message)
        mail.close()

  [1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer
```

Comment: It is also probably better to just log a hash of the content, instead of the content itself. This avoids leaking data and saves storage space, also comparisons are easier.

Comment: I get this when I put the code in.
csvfile = 'odds.csv/odds-log-{0}'.format(datetime.today().strftime('%-d_%-m'))
ValueError: Invalid format string
Do you have to create a csv file or does the code it for you?
Also, do I use the entire email sending code and where do I paste it? On a new line or indented after c_writer.writerow([dfmerge2[0], dfmerge3[0]])

Comment: I'm not sure why you get invalid format string. Check that the datetime import is correct. If you can't get it to work, you can build the string for the file name in another way instead of format. The code creates the csv file. Paste the email sending code where indicated by the comment, indented within the if block. The with block is for writing the data to csv.

Comment: Thankyou, that worked. However, now I get the error '  File "C:\Users\Harrison Pollock\Desktop\Test.py", line 57, in <module>
    with open(csvfile,'a') as wfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'odds.csv/odds-log-03-03'

Comment: I'm not sure on your system configuration, what version of python you're using or why that would happen. '.csv' is after the {0} in the format string, `'<path to log file>/odds-log-{0}.csv'`,so I can't see how you'd get that result. Double check the format string is correct for the file path you want to use. {0} is the part of the string that is replaced with the date. Otherwise use a different method of creating the string for the file path.

Comment: I edited the answer to to show how I'd adapt the example to your code. It's not tested.